# LED breathing circuit

Tags: led, led-driver

I'm trying to build a circuit which will involve 20 LEDs and run from a 8.4 - 7.2 V Li-po battery.

I have assembled [this circuit](https://ledcalculator.net/#p=8&v=3&c=20&n=20&o=w%5B1%5D) on a breadboard and it works great.

I have also spent many days watching YouTube videos on "Breathing LED Circuits" and have made this circuit successfully:

[Breathing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xyi6eaRnn9c&t=182s)

However, this person is only using 2 LEDs and a 12 V power source. I can't figure out how to make my 20 LED array (first link) to work with the breathing circuit.

I was told it id possible to have 20 LEDs breath in sync, and on a 7.4-8.1 V Li-po battery pack. I have many resistor values on hand as well asssorted capacitors & BC transistors.

I know enough about electronic circuits to get me in trouble and I am desparate to get my project completed. This is the only thing holding me up.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does the video include a schematic? If so, post it here. If not, draw as a schematic what the video shows being built. The *lingua franca* of electronic engineering is the schematic - not a video. Once you have a schematic, then it becomes possible to show how to make the two concepts work together.

Comment: With 20 LEDs, it may be better to drive them using PWM. You can use another NE555, or the dual NE556.

Comment: If you already have 2 LEDs 'breathing' why can't you just connect all 20 in parallel in place of those 2? Also a schematic of what you're trying to do would be very helpful.

Comment: Floppydisk, That was the first thing I tried-No Joy

Comment: Neil, the Breathing Video has no Schematic....wish it did. I just followed along the video and reproduced it on a breadboard. Drawing a Schematic is way over my head. I have 0 formal education in electronic circuitry. I learn by watching and hopefully grasping the concept....and reading of course.

Answer (score 1):

From the video it seems that the LEDs are connected in parallel. This has the advantage that the constraint on VCE is more relaxed; this also has the disadvantage that the every LEDs absorbs the current necessary for providing the lighting function.

So you have to change the transistor to make you project work, and use branches of 1 LED and 1 220 Ohm series resistor for each LED. You will need the battery and the BJT to work with at least 400 mA, so check the datasheet!

Note that the battery time in hours is {capacity of the battery [mAh] / 400 mA}.

The circuit will be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmI71S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Add branches, but remember that Q1 and battery must support the current for all the LEDs

Comment: With a 1k resistor in the supply you won't get 4mA into the LEDs, never mind 400.

Comment: you're right, I forgot it in the equations. So, no problem for the current limiting, temperature and related problems. I think also that the luminosity will not be a problem with this solution

Answer (score 0):

An LED boost driver with PWM control will do this very efficiently. This allows connecting the LEDs in series with active current control. This will yield even brightness while minimizing losses.

Look for a booster unit that supports the voltage-in you require (6-12V, say) and can output up to 36V. For 20 LEDs you would wire them in two strings of 10, each string with a small load resistor to absorb any difference in forward voltage.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness & suggestions. Its very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an adaptation of the circuit in the video (which appears to use a single BJT). This uses a TO-220 Darlington transistor since you have 20 LEDs. Average current draw from the battery is about 75mA and average power dissipation of the TIP120 is around 300mW so it does not require a heat sink.

The current shown is that in a single LED, so the total current is approximately 20x that (plus a bit for the oscillator itself).

[image]

Of course, a microcontroller driving PWM into a MOSFET  would be a more elegant solution and would allow the "breathing" profile to be adjusted to whatever your preference might be. On the other hand, this does not require any programming or knowledge or resources thereof.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. Your advice is well taken and appreciated. Like I said, I basically know nothing about electronics with the only thing going for me is the eagerness to learn and try and figure it out. Even reading a Schematic is a challenge, much less the ability to produce one. Everyones comments are taken seriously and I will do my best to implement it. In case anyone is wondering, I fly RC Helicopters & Drones. This lighting system is for a Helo landing pad I'm trying to make.